# Could a student with plagiarism in assignment get a high grade in a class?

Tags: graduate-school, plagiarism, gpa, homework, canada

This semester I took a course and the prof is very restrict with the assignments, I had special circumstances (due to my research and my displacement), which required me to commute between cities to attend the classes. I was 3-1 hours late in submitting my assignments and he was considering big penalties for that. (What I mean is a delay in submission, and it was not more than a day.)

I think penalties are good if the prof is going to give us feedback and assignment grades during the semester, before finals. But this prof announced the assignment grade a week after our final exam, and he still considers those big penalties.

I am in my graduate studies, I rarely have seen such penalties for a grad student, for being late for a day as we all are busy with our research and thises. These things are for undergrads.

I noticed that a classmate who was caught by the same prof for one plagiarized assignment got a high grade. That guy copied all of his assignments from another guy in the class and got caught only once. I was really shocked when I noticed that guy got A+ even though he did plagiarize. (plagiarism happened in the current course, and the current assignment, his ultimate grade came high, he plagiarized in the assignments and got caught in only one) {The classmates who got caught told me that they got caught and also showed prof's email regarding their plagiarized assignment }

I did not plagiarize and my circumstances were unique in the class, he considered penalties for my late submissions, and he is a hard grader. I also asked my advisor to communicate my circumstances but the instructor never considered any exception for me. I am in my last semester and now I have the lowest mark from him in my A+ GPA.

Is this fair to give hight grade to a person that did plagiarism and put such penalties for late submission?

By late submission, I mean that you submit your assignment a day late. Max a day late.

**Edited: Late announcement of assignments grade is a harmful and stupid thing because the assignments are supposed to be graded on time, a week, or 2 weeks after submission. The prof did not grade and give us feedback during the semester and he graded them after our final exam. Assignments are for improvements and we only can improve ourselves if we get feedback at the right time, NOT AT THE END OF SEMESTER. End of semester is a bit late for getting grades for assignments.**

Comment: _this prof announced the assignment grade a week after our final exam Which is hilarious_: Why is that?

Comment: What does "3-1 hours late" mean?

Comment: The way you write here will not make you friends (or upvotes). Why do you care about what grades other people get? Why is this "hilarious"? And why shouldn't it be fair? The prof probably has leeway (for good or bad reasons) to punish different crimes differently, or does he violate university rules?

Comment: What you describe seems fair to me except for the "nonsense reasons" in the penultimate paragraph. Could you describe them instead? Were they really nonsense (like grading you not for academic reasons, but for other reasons?)?

Comment: I think the writing of the question can be improved. However, OP is not wrong in observing that the prof is clearly negligent to check for plagiarism on their side while marking down for negligence on the student side. In other words, not applying the same principles to their own duty as they apply to the student. If the plagiarism happened in some other work, then this is irrelevant, of course, but it is not clear here whether it was previous plagiarism that OP complains about or plagiarism in the current assignment.

Comment: We had assignments and plagiarism happened in the current assignment, in the current course.

Comment: Could you explain how many hours you were lated, if the prof knew about the plagiarism (except for this one ocasation) and what the "nonsense reasons" refernto? And maybe, if you have time, also answer the other questions from my comment?

Comment: To confirm: the other student got an A+, despite committing plagiarism on the very assignment he got an A+ for? Well, that's clearly the prof's checks not working correctly. On the other hand, checking for delayed submission is far easier. Do you have proof that the other student has plagiarised? If yes, you could raise a complaint to the examinations office (or whoever is responsible for fair grading at your place) that the assessment does not provide an equitable opportunity for the participants.

Comment: This is little more than a rant. The body contains no answerable question.

Comment: _It is hilarious because the assignments are supposed to be graded on time, a week, or 2 weeks after submission._ Is it a week? Or two weeks? Is this your opinion or formal policy? _Assignments are for improvements and we only can improve ourselves if we get feedback at the right time_ Is this your opinion or formal policy? _The end of semester is a bit late for getting grades for assignments._ Why?

Comment: I guess we have different definitions, but I think it's a bit childish for a graduate student to be unable to find a way to get their assignments in on time regularly. A one-off special circumstance is one thing, whereas your post here comes off as extremely entitled. It's not typical for a grad student to be penalized so much for lateness because it's not typical for them to be so late. Yet you expect assignments to be returned to you graded on a schedule you prefer when you won't do the assignments on one?

Comment: @BryanKrause: While this answer really come off as entitled and childish, I think the answerer has a problem with the penality because the lecturer is late with returning them. (And to be fair, this is bad -- the students most likely have no way to penalize the professor for being late.)

Comment: As a graduate student, you should be learning how to take facts, distill them, and write a coherent summary. Maybe apply those skills to this question?

Comment: @ Kathy, thank you for the advice, I am a non-English speaker.  I think my question is clear.

Comment: @ user111388 , he is a hard grader. please read the edited version.

Comment: @user111388 I agree it's bad pedagogy to delay returning assignments, but that has to be a complaint from other students in the class who are capable of meeting their own deadlines, not from the one who can't. Justifying your own bad behavior with someone else's is an irresponsible path.

Comment: @BryanKrause: I disagree here. i think it's appropriate by students who are never late and also by those students who are late and get penalized for that.

Comment: @Bryan Krause, students, all are paying tuition. it's appropriate for all students attending class.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Sadly, I must agree with the others that I don't see an answerable question here. Moreover, litigating your professor's actions ("is it fair that...?) here will not be constructive.

Answer (score 3):

> I noticed that a classmate who was caught...for one plagiarized assignment got a high grade

They plagiarized in the past, there's no reason they cannot reform and get a high grade.

> [The prof] applied penalties for my late submissions and took marks for nonsense reasons.

Marks were removed for lateness, not nonsense reasons.

> Is this fair?

Yes: It is reasonable that student got a high grade, whilst you were penalised for lateness.

It would be unfair if students were able to submit assignments late to get extra time.

---

EDIT: The revised question claims the student with a high grade plagiarised to get the grade. It remains unclear if this is speculation or fact. Regardless, it remains fair that the OP was punished for lateness.

Comment: How do you mean, by "past"? The plagiarism happened on the same course and the same prof caught it.

Comment: @programmer Past meaning: Not the assignment they got a high grade on.